# How do I read dimension names from a file with a contingency table in R

Tags: r, dimensions, contingency

I have an input data file (say, pets.csv)as a contingency table

As for example, so

```
          Animal
        Dog    Cat
Color
Black    15   20
White    30   60
```

So, the dimension names are  Animal and  Color.  Is there a way to read this into R with the dimension names?

Currently, I input the file as simply

```
       Dog    Cat
Black    15   20
White    30   60
```

and do

```r
mytable<-read.csv("pets.csv", header = TRUE, row.names=1)
```

But that loses the names of these variables (`Color` and `Animal)`.
I see that I can input the file completely as numbers  and input the names in dimnames, but I would rather just read the file. I get tons of tables in files.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to make a custom function for this. Let's assume we have copied and pasted your table, above, into Excel, and saved it as `animal_colors.csv`. Then you could set up a function like this:

```
read_ctable <- function(x) {
  # get the variable names from first two lines
  vars <- readLines(x, 2)  
  # remove comma separators
  vars <- gsub(',', '', vars)  
  # read in data starting on third line
  df <- read.csv(x, header=T, row.names=1, skip=2)
  # convert to table
  dt <- as.table(as.matrix(df))  
  # add variable names (have to reverse, because of the order in which they appeared in the file)
  names(attributes(dt)$dimnames) <- rev(vars)  
  return(dt)
}
```

When I call `read_ctable('animal_colors.csv')` on a CSV file set up as above, this is the output:

```
       Animal
Color   Dog Cat
  Black  15  20
  White  30  60
```

This is an `array` object, which IMO is less useful than the data frame object you get from just calling `read.csv`, but you can call `as.data.frame` on it to get a nice tidy data frame for further analysis:

```
  Color Animal Freq
1 Black    Dog   15
2 White    Dog   30
3 Black    Cat   20
4 White    Cat   60
```